# How to animate Width property in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

Is there any way that I can animate width property of the window in WPF to go from both 0 and its max width to some given point, at the same time. I know this code is not correct, but just to give you an example of what I want

```
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="600" To="300" Duration="0:0:1"/>
<DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" From="0" To="300" Duration="0:0:1"/>
```

So, it would go from both 0 and 600 to meet at 300 and then disappear.

Comment: It can't go from both to both at the same time, so no. If you want to "squeeze" the item, consider using a `ScaleTransform` instead

Comment: This could work if you provided some valid parameters.For the same duration you are doing both of the things in parallel, that's just wrong.